# Do not include the database column when query string is NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to make a search functionality. The code below says that if `Port`, `Status` and TIN are not null then query the database.

> E.g 1. If User has chosen the port and status but not the TIN then the
>   TIN should not be included when searching the database.
>
> E.g 2. If User has chosen the port only then the Status and TIN should
>   not be included when searching the database.

**Code**

```
        int Port = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Port"]);
        var Status = Request.QueryString["Status"];
        var TIN = Request.QueryString["TIN"];

        List<Transaction> QueriedTransactionList;
        QueriedTransactionList = db.Transactions.ToList();

        TransactionViewModel TransactionViewModel = new TransactionViewModel();
        List<TransactionViewModel> TransactionDataList = QueriedTransactionList.Select(x => new TransactionViewModel{
            TTransactionID = x.TTransactionID,
            BatchID = x.BatchID,
            TransactionDateTime = x.TransactionDateTime,
            TransactionStatus = x.TransactionStatus,
            TaxPayerName = x.Card.TaxPayer.TaxPayerName,
            TaxPayerEmail = x.Card.TaxPayer.TaxPayerEmail,
            TaxPayerTIN = x.Card.TaxPayer.TaxPayerTIN,
            DispatchBy = x.User.UserName,
            DestinationPort = x.Card.Port.PortName,
            BatchCards = Helper.GetBatchQtyByBatchID(x.BatchID)
        }).GroupBy(x => x.BatchID).Select(x => x.LastOrDefault()).Where(x => Status.IndexOf(x.TransactionStatus, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 && TIN.IndexOf(x.Card.TaxPayerTIN, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).OrderByDescending(x => x.TTransactionID).ToList();
```

Comment: Build a `IQueryable<T>` using `if` blocks - `QueriedTransactionList = db.Transactions;` (not `.ToList()`) `if (Port != null) { QueriedTransactionList = QueriedTransactionList.Where(....);` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke The OP doesn't looking for a query filtering but for projecting some columns or not based on the value of some variables.

Comment: @CodeNotFound, If that is the case, then its related to the UI, not the query so what OP has shown does not make much sense

Comment: @CodeNotFound is that your reading of "not included"? I, and seemingly Stephen, thought it meant not to include that field in the search criteria (i.e. the where clause). In which case Stephen's suggestion is correct. If they don't want to see that field in the results when it wasn't part of the search criteria (which seems odd to me, but there you go) then it _could_ be achieved in this code by using alternative .Select() statements to pick the required fields, but would still need some change to the UI as well, potentially.

Comment: Perhaps Jeffrey can clarify the meaning of the question?